# Moving from TFS on-prem to cloud - need to change connection method

Tags: azure, powershell, tfs

The TFS is moving to Azure and I need to convert a function to work with token but don't know how.

The function checks is a path exists or not until now it worked but now it will not because I need to use a token

```
function CheckTfsPathExistance
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $tfsPath,
        [string] $userName,
        [string] $userPassword,
        [string] $userDomain
    )

    Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Net.Http'

    $clientHandler = New-Object System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler

    if($userName)
    {
        $clientHandler.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($userName, $userPassword, $userDomain)
    }
    else
    {
        $clientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = 1
    }
    
    $client = New-Object System.Net.Http.HttpClient($clientHandler)

    #TFS path
    $tfsBranchPath = "https://tfs.bandit.com/DefaultCollection/Idu Client-Server/_apis/tfvc/items?scopePath=$tfsPath"


    Write-Host "Sending get request (items api) to url: " $tfsBranchPath
    $response = $client.GetAsync($tfsBranchPath).Result
    $contentObjects = $response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result | ConvertFrom-Json

    $exists = $contentObjects.count -gt 0
    
    return $exists
}

$tfsBranchPath should be replaced with:
"https://dev.azure.com/bandit-TFS31-dryrun/Idu Client-Server/_apis/tfvc/items?scopePath=$tfsFilePath"
```

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps?view=azps-10.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When moving to Azure DevOps, you'll need to use Personal Access Tokens (PAT) for authentication instead of username and password. Here's how you can modify your function to work with a PAT:

1. Replace the $userName, $userPassword, and $userDomain parameters with a $personalAccessToken parameter.
2. Adjust the client handler to use the PAT for authentication.
3. Update the TFS path to the new Azure DevOps URL.

modified function:

```
function CheckTfsPathExistance
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $tfsPath,
        [string] $personalAccessToken
    )

    Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Net.Http'

    $clientHandler = New-Object System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler
    $client = New-Object System.Net.Http.HttpClient($clientHandler)

    # Use PAT for authentication
    $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalAccessToken)"))
    $client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = [System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue]::new("Basic", $base64AuthInfo)

    # Updated Azure DevOps path
    $tfsBranchPath = "https://dev.azure.com/bandit-TFS31-dryrun/Idu Client-Server/_apis/tfvc/items?scopePath=$tfsPath"

    Write-Host "Sending get request (items api) to url: " $tfsBranchPath
    $response = $client.GetAsync($tfsBranchPath).Result
    $contentObjects = $response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result | ConvertFrom-Json

    $exists = $contentObjects.count -gt 0

    return $exists
}
```

When using the function, you'll need to pass in the path and your PAT:

```
$exists = CheckTfsPathExistance -tfsPath "/path/on/server" -personalAccessToken "YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

You can generate PAT using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows

Comment: Thank you @Daredevil
It's not working. It seems that the command is not exist

The property 'Authorization' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:15 char:5
+     $clientHandler.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = ("Basic $bas ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

What should I need to do that I will have $clientHandler.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization

Comment: Why New-Object System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler does not contain DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization?

Comment: Updated Answer to use HttpClient. @Bandit

Comment: Thank you very much @Daredevil
Do you know for how long the token is valid? this is how its created:

[PSCredential]$creds = Get-Credential
$null = Connect-AzAccount -Credential $creds -ErrorAction Stop
$accessToken = (Get-AzAccessToken -ErrorAction Stop).Token

I am using the accessToken for the Base64
My script is verifying a lot of files against TFS for every file I need to create a new accessToken?

Comment: In Azure DevOps you can generate a PAT which can be valid for upto a year. and then use that instead, check the link I shared about generating PAT.

Comment: Yes I know this but I need to use a short time token therefor I am using AzAccessToken but I don’t know for how long it’s valid